# PayPal Restful API: is there a way to refund multiple transactions in one request?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

In my use case, I sometimes need to refund multiple transactions at once. Instead of making each refund request individually, is there a way to pass in multiple transaction ID with refund amount and execute them altogether?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to process a refund for multiple transactions in one request. You will need to send the requests individually with specific transaction id for a refund.